# getting error in FBSDKAppInviteDialog (Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 "(null)")

Tags: ios, fbsdksharedialog, fbsdkappinvitecontent

i have succesfully created AppId in facebook.developer.i also add urlscheme in info.plist file.

here is my code

```
var inviteDialog : FBSDKAppInviteDialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()
        if(inviteDialog.canShow()){
            let appLinkUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://fb.me/*******")!
            let previewImageUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://yourwebpage.com/preview-image.png")!

            let inviteContent:FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
            inviteContent.appLinkURL = appLinkUrl as URL!
            inviteContent.appInvitePreviewImageURL = previewImageUrl as URL!

            inviteDialog.content = inviteContent
            inviteDialog.delegate = self
            inviteDialog.show()
        }
```

does not show invite dialogue box getting error like

Comment: am also facing same issue.Did you got any solution?My error is XPC connection interrupted
some(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9

Comment: @Sakshi still getting same issue if you got any solution pls tell me. i think facebook stop providing app invite process.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/ . Even I got same info from this link

Comment: @Sakshi yes i also check.you have old app or new ?

Comment: It's new app and was working like 6 months back.Suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @Sakshi s2u in my app app invite was working 1 year. before 1 month stop.than after i change facebook to whatsapp invite

Comment: i also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. So, I downloaded the latest SDK and found that App Invites are no longer supported from Facebook SDK version 4.28 and above. I downloaded the latest SDK version 4.33.0 from [developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/) and when I opened FBSDKAppInviteDialog class and found that the below methods are deprecated and are written as below.

```
+ (instancetype)showFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                           withContent:(FBSDKAppInviteContent *)content
                              delegate:(id<FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate>)delegate
__attribute__ ((deprecated("App Invites no longer supported")));


/**

 - Warning:use showFromViewController:withContent:delegate: instead
 */
+ (instancetype)showWithContent:(FBSDKAppInviteContent *)content delegate:(id<FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate>)delegate
__attribute__ ((deprecated("use showFromViewController:withContent:delegate: instead")));
```